# KMS Remote streaming issue in AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I installed the KurentoMediaServer in my local machine using the link
http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation_guide.html and started the KurentoMedia Server

```
     sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
```

2.Then downloaded the Kurento-tutorial-js from the github link https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js and from the hello world folder, start the http server using the command

```
     bower install
     http-server
```

3.From the browser,i loaded the link

```
  http://localhost:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
```

Both the **Local streaming** and the **Remote streaming** works well

4.I installed the KMS and the http server in the **AWS Ubuntu 14.04**

5.Now when i loaded the page in the browser

```
http://*serverip*:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://*serverip*:8888/kurento
```

Only the Local streaming is working ,but the **remote streaming is not working**

6.When i checked the log no errors,but the request hit the server.

Do i want to change anything in the server side configuration?
 How to solve this issue?

***Editing i have tried:***

**Kurento.Conf.json** file

```
      "WebRtcEndpoint" : {
     "stunServerAddress" : "173.194.66.127", 
     "stunServerPort" : 19302
    }
```

**WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini** file:

Uncommented the following lines

```
  stunServerAddress=173.194.66.127
  stunServerPort=19302
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a STUN server in your KMS configuration. Check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kurento/aws$20stun/kurento/QkO_ct0QEGE/DHOPo3f5V3EJ) in the project's mailing list, or [this](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers) page from the online documentation.

Watch out, as libnice does not support CNAMEs. You'll have to use IPs instead. Check the selected STUN server with [this test page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

---

EDIT 1

The server you used (173.194.66.127) is not working. Please do check with the test page posted with a different STUN server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @igracia,
I followed the KMS STUN configuration based on the above link,I added Stun ip address and port in **WebRtcEndpoint.config.ini** ,it doesn't work.Also made changes in **kurento.conf.json** but the same result.The remote streaming not working.What i have to do to solve this?

Comment: Can you edit your post indicating how you edited your configuration files, please?

Comment: @santoscadenas ,i have updated the question above,pls check and reply.

Comment: @CibinWilliam if the answer is correct, please accept it as valid answer.

Comment: @igracia i done it using TURN server ,which i have answered below

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above problem by installing the TURN server

For the installation of the TURN server i followed the link
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/faq.html

After successfully install the TURN server and done the changes given in the documentation

Start the service using **sudo service coturn start** and the start the kurento server

Now the Remote streaming is also working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stun server that you added is not valid, as @igracia says on its response, you have to check the STUN server with [this page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) and ensure that you have reflexive candidates, not only host ones.