# Kurento Client-js for newly created module in Localhost

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I created a new module with reference to the link http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html using the command

```
    kurento-module-scaffold.sh <module_name> <output_directory> opencv_filter
```

2.A module i created, in the */src/server/interface/.json* file added the parameters needed.

3.Now run the cmake which generate the cpp files in *src/server/implementation/object/*

4.Fix the changes in cpp file and generated the so using the command

```
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && make && sudo make install
```

**For the client-js:**

5.To create a js folder run the following command

```
    cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
```

6.From the js folder,run the following command to generate dist folder which contain the three js files.

```
    npm install grunt grunt-browserify grunt-contrib-clean grunt-jsdoc grunt-npm2bower-sync minifyify
```

Then run the command

```
    grunt
```

**Client-js:**

1.Created a client folder with reference to the kms-crowddetctor folder from the link https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js

2.Inside the *bower-component*,added a module folder which contain the js files generated in the *dist* folder

3.In the index.html and edit the newly added js path(in the bower_components)

4.In the index.js ,change the name module name as the name in the bower_components.

Then i start the Kurento Media Server and the http-server and loaded the page in the browser

```
  http://localhost:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://localhost:8888/kurento#
```

Only the local stream is working,the remote stream is not working but it does not shows any error.Help me to move forward.

The dropbox link for the module code is https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3m17afrmnf8af5/opencv_filter.tar.gz?dl=0

The dropbox link for the client-js code is https://www.dropbox.com/s/ty1u1tbxa6y1tlc/client_sample.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Probably the issue is related with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087188/kms-remote-streaming-issue-in-aws-ubuntu-instance

Comment: @santoscadenas Now I am tesing in localhost,The opencv sample works fine,but when adding new module,remote streaming doesn't works.The above link you have pointed occurs when deploying in AWS server.

Comment: @CibinWilliam You'll need to check the media server logs to see if there is something standing out in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved the error,The error solvd when i replace "extends": "Filter" with "extends": "OpenCVFilter" in the kmd **json** file